# Custom bottom navigation android studio icon

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to create a custom navView in my app but I get this weirdest bug.
[image: bottomNavNiew]
I can't get the "menu" button to look like the others.
It's not pressed in the image, it just like that all the time.

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.BottomNavView">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:theme="@style/NavTheme"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0."
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_bar"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my theme:

```
    <style name="NavTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorBlue</item>
    <item name="colorNavigationItemSelected">@color/colorGray</item>
</style>
```

- itried `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` as well.

this is my menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:title="@string/menu"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:title="@string/map"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/liked"
    android:title="@string/heart"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/liked"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:title="@string/plus"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/add"/>
</menu>
```

the image is [image: list]
I can't understand why it's have the text beneath and this different look.

Answer (score 1):

use `labelVisibilityMode` to `unlabeled` to remove the text under the menu item

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```